# retrieve messages from google chat to a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract google chat threads from spaces in which there are standard messages like:
Help - Case 123456
what i would like to do is to export that data to a google sheet and also include the names of the user who started the thread and or commented, only messages from today from specific space, i know how to send messages to google chat via api rest by following the [doc](https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python) but i cant find a way to retrieve data, i can't seem to understand how to do it via webhooks, any thoughts? i will be heartly thankful if anyone could help me with this.

```
from json import dumps

from httplib2 import Http


def main():
    """Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart."""
    url = '<INCOMING-WEBHOOK-URL>'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : 'Hello from a Python script!'}

    message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What language is your code written in? It does not look like google apps script.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to retrieve messages from a chat using the API.

If you think of it as a good feature, you can fill out a Feature Request on https://developers.google.com/chat/support#missing_features

As I can see, there are other developers requesting the [same feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:350158%2B%20status:open%20type:feature_request%20get%20messages), so it's most likely Google is working on that, since the API is relatively new